# Repair installation and Service Packs

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010, repair

What happens if:

1. I install VS2010.
2. I install VS2010 SP1.
3. I run VS2010's Repair installation because of some problem in VS2010.

At this point, do I need to install SP1 again? In simple words, is the Repair Installation intelligent enough not to overwrite newer versions of files (from SP1) with the old ones that it has? Or is it that the Repair Install will simply bulldoze everything to original state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a repair you must re-apply the service packs and roll-ups.

After uninstalling a Service Pack or roll-up you must also repair Visual Studio before re-applying them.